# Access denied error while performing a SPFx deployment through Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint-online, spfx, cicd

[image]I am facing Access denied error while performing a SPFx deployment through Azure DevOps. The error says, "Error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource". I am using a service account to deploy the sppkg file on App Catalogue, which has Site collection admin permission level, and The account which I am using on dev-ops is my corporate account. I am also able to connect to SPO Online successfully.
The command where this error is coming is like this:

```
o365 spo app add -p $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_myCI/drop/sharepoint/solution/myspfx.sppkg --overwrite --appCatalogUrl https://$(tenant).sharepoint.com/$(catalogsite) --scope sitecollection
```

Comment: Did you run `o365 login` before running the app add command? Could you share your devops pipeline?

Comment: STEP 1: Use Node 10.x //ALL OK--
STEP 2:install -g @pnp/office365-cli //ALL OK--
STEP 3: o365 spo app add -p $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_myCI/drop/sharepoint/solution/myspfx.sppkg --overwrite --appCatalogUrl https://$(tenant).sharepoint.com/$(catalogsite) --scope sitecollection //Throws error: Error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT added screenshot and steps

Comment: You might need to move the script `o365 spo app add` to the Step `Connect SPO Site`.  If you login in your SPO site using a script task. The console session will be closed when the  task is completed and that might cause the login session cannot persist in the following steps.

Comment: how can I write both commands in one action item? Not sure about the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the script o365 spo app add to the Step Connect SPO Site. See below syntax using `"|"` to run multiple line scripts in the script task.

```
- script: |
   Connect SPO Site
   o365 spo app add
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#bash) for example in bash task.

Comment: multilines seems to be not working, only the top most command works

Comment: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: Hi Levi, I somehow managed to run all the commands from one CMD and it shows me the following error now:2021-06-04T13:38:33.2858050Z Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
2021-06-04T13:38:34.7544462Z Error: Access denied.

Comment: @RishiVedpathi Could try using `-powershell` task if you are using windows-agent.

Comment: I tried the same commands from Powershell on my local machine. The error is :  Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)). The conclusion now is I am unable to do it from my local machine itself , can you please tell me that the service account from which I am trying to deploy sppkg file should be added anywhere else in SPO? it currently has site collection permission rights and app catalogue also resides on the same site collection.